# How do I move the System Settings icon to the right. Or at least duplicate it to the right

Tags: mac

What I want is the System Settings icon to look like Mac. That is the only thing that takes away the feeling of it being one. **thanks!**

Comment: Please clarify the question: What session indicator are you talking about? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: the one that looks like a gear. (or for me, the apple logo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install Cairo Dock for this.

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

After installing start Cairo from Dash. You will have  a dock like in Mac OS at the bottom.
Go to its configuration menu by right clicking on the dock and going to Configure.
There you can move the dock from bottom to right.

[image]
 Then here it what you get:

[image]

And of course you can customise the dock and remove or add launchers to the dock.You can remove all launchers except System Settings button, as well.

[image]

*I like Ubuntu for its customizing abilities! Do you?*

Comment: Good one!  (and an upvote!)